# Direct and Reciprocal lattice common point

Tags: fourier-transform, crystals

Does a reciprocal lattice have a common point with its direct lattice? 
(possibly at the origin $\vec{K}=\vec{R}=\vec{0}$)

Answer (score 7):

You are comparing apples with oranges. $\vec k$ has the unit $1/\mathrm{Length}$, and $\vec r$ has the unit $\mathrm{Length}$.

It is true that every lattice and reciprocal lattice contain the origin. When the lattice is cubic with lattice constant $1$, the real and the reciprocal lattice are indeed completely identical, but this is of no importance whatsoever.

Imagine that a car is resting at the origin. Then, $\vec v=(0,0,0)$ and $\vec r=(0,0,0)$. They are the same, but the units as well as the *meaning* are different. It's the same with direct and reciprocal lattice vectors.

The only relation between reciprocal lattice vectors and real lattice vectors is

$$\vec k_i\cdot\vec r_j=n\delta_{ij},$$

where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: That is correct. It does not make sense to compare points in position space with points in momentum space.

Comment: :) the scales are NOT comparable but the directions ARE. For example a (normal) vector $\vec{k}$ represents parallel crystal planes.

Comment: If you are talking about the Miller indices: You can also use the real lattice vectors for that.